# Android serial port over WiFi

Tags: android, serial-port, wifi

I'm trying to implement a car controlled by HTC Desize Z. I have a car which is being controlled by serial port, the data flows into serial port [through this](http://www.spezial.cz/connectblue/wireless-lan-wifi-seriove-rs232-oem-moduly.html).

But how do I connect to the board through WiFi? I know the RxTx library, it's even been ported to Android, but I have absolutely no clue how to use it, or where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you if this would work for your specific device but normally these serial over WiFi adapters take the serial data in and then expect you to connect or listen for a TCP/IP socket connection from the WiFi device and the serial data is tunneled over the socket.

You should read the documentation for that device and see if that is true for this device. Usually the WiFi board has a telnet server that you can connect to, to configure the device, and then as part of the configuration you specify an IP address and port for the device to try to connect to when it wants to send serial data.

Comment: Yeah, you're right after digging a little bit more into the documentation I found it. Create the WiFi, connect to it with the telnet on specific address and port, but then what? Telnet is used for bidirectional text based communication, so I really don't know what to send there to set the serial port pins correctly:-/ There are some AT commands, but I dunno what it means and I haven't found anything specific for using the serial port itself, maybe I'm looking bad. Damn it...

Comment: Is the documentation available online? If so can you point me to it. I might be able to help out if I can see that document.